# Trouble with memory in C#

Tags: c#, memory

I want to draw a loading circle (.gif) on the screen, while the applications is loading something big. But I can't run the circle as fast as I want, because I get memory issues. Does anyone know how to solve these (on 75 ms instead of 1000ms)? And how to remove the circle when done (it doesn't disappear any more).

EDIT: The load function is executed when the window size changes.

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartUp();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    bool onrun;
    bool done;
    System.Threading.Timer timer;
    GifImage Circle;
    Point center;

    void StartUp()
    {
        onrun = true;
        done = false;
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(Animate));
        timer.Change(0, 500);
    }

    void Animate(object sender)
    {
        if (onrun == true)
        {
            Circle = new GifImage("circleAnim.gif");
            Circle.ReverseAtEnd = false;
            int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
            center = new Point((width / 2) - 150, (height / 2) - 150);
            onrun = false;
        }
        else if (done == true)
        {
            timer.Dispose();
        }

        Image i = Circle.GetNextFrame();
        System.Drawing.Graphics GraphicsObject = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
        try
        {
            GraphicsObject.DrawImage(i, center);
            i.Dispose();
            GraphicsObject.Dispose();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int hduizend = 100000;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100000000; i++)
        {
            hduizend /= 2;
            hduizend *= 2;
        }

        done = true;
    }
```

EDIT2 (error):
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".

Also the gif image itself is not the problem:

```
public class GifImage
{
private Image gifImage;
private FrameDimension dimension;
private int frameCount;
private int currentFrame = -1;
private bool reverse;
private int step = 1;

public GifImage(string path)
{
    gifImage = Image.FromFile(path); 
    dimension = new FrameDimension(gifImage.FrameDimensionsList[0]); 
    frameCount = gifImage.GetFrameCount(dimension); 
}

public bool ReverseAtEnd 
{
    get { return reverse; }
    set { reverse = value; }
}

public Image GetNextFrame()
{

    currentFrame += step;


    if (currentFrame >= frameCount || currentFrame < 1)
    {
        if (reverse)
        {
            step *= -1;
            currentFrame += step; 
        }
        else
            currentFrame = 0;
    }
    return GetFrame(currentFrame);
}

public Image GetFrame(int index)
{
    gifImage.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, index); 
    return (Image)gifImage.Clone(); 
}
```

}

Comment: What memory issues do you get?

Comment: I didn't think .NET had support for .gif files - if you are using a 3rd party library it's quite possibly a limitation of their implementation.  Hard to say without attaching a profiler or something.

Comment: "I get memory issues" is absolutely meaningless unless you explain what "memory issues" means. Do you just stop remembering to pick up milk on the way home? Does your circle forget it's a circle and start drawing a square instead? Do you get out of memory errors or access violations? Any of those three qualify as "memory issues", and we can't see your screen or read your mind from where we sit.

Comment: appears to be using GDI via System.Drawing (see the GifImage class), without more information I'm going to take the wild guess and assume that the issue is caused by a bad memory allocation in GDI caused by not disposing resources in managed code (when using System.Drawing, Dispose early and often)

Answer (score 1):

assign the gif to a PictureBox and just show the Picturebox when needed.  It will take care of the animation.  You just need to take care of when it needs to be shown and of positioning it then.

```
private PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
Image animatedPicture = Image.FromFile(path);

...
int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds. 
int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
center = new Point((width / 2) - 150, (height / 2) - 150);
pictureBox.Location = center;
pictureBox.Visible = true;
```